# Spring mail support - no subject

Tags: java, spring, email

I have updated my libraries, and now e-mails are sent without subject. I don't know where this happened...

Mail API is 1.4.3., Spring 2.5.6. and Spring Integration Mail 1.0.3.RELEASE.

```
<!-- Definitions for SMTP server -->
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="${mail.host}" />
    <property name="username" value="${mail.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${mail.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="adminMailTemplate" class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage" >
    <property name="from" value="${mail.admin.from}" />
    <property name="to" value="${mail.admin.to}" />
    <property name="cc">
        <list>
            <value>${mail.admin.cc1}</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Mail service definition -->
<bean id="mailService" class="net.bbb.core.service.impl.MailServiceImpl">
    <property name="sender" ref="mailSender"/>
    <property name="mail" ref="adminMailTemplate"/>
</bean>
```

And properties mail.host,mail.username,mail.password,mail.admin.from,mail.admin.to,
mail.admin.cc1.

Java class:

```
/** The sender. */
private MailSender sender;

/** The mail. */
private SimpleMailMessage mail;

public void sendMail() {
    this.mail.setSubject("Subject");

    this.mail.setText("msg body");          

    try {
        getSender().send(this.mail);
    } catch (MailException e) {
        log.error("Error sending mail!",e);
    }
}

public SimpleMailMessage getMail() {
    return this.mail;
}

public void setMail(SimpleMailMessage mail) {
    this.mail = mail;
}

public MailSender getSender() {
    return this.sender;
}

public void setSender(MailSender mailSender1) {
    this.sender = mailSender1;
}
```

Everything worked before, I am wondering if there may be any conflicts with new libraries.

Comment: Did you find the problem? I'm facing it as well, so I would love it if you could follow up with the answer :).

Comment: It is not so necessary at the moment, but I will try to find it until the end of the week.

Comment: I found the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010296/javamail-not-sending-subject-or-from-under-jettyrun-war (excluding certain jars pulled in as dependencies)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally - I had the time to resolve this.

In pom.xml, I have added java mail dependency and remove exclusion for geronimo javamail in apache axis transport http dependency.

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
<exclusions>
<exclusion>
<groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
<artifactId>geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec</artifactId>
</exclusion>
</exclusions>  </dependency>

Answer (score 1):

I expect it's something to do with the way that you're injecting a singleton `SimpleMailMessage` into your bean. This is not thread-safe, since every call to your `sendMail` method will be using the same underlying `SimpleMailmessage` object. It's quite possible that some implementation change in the new libraries now means this is broken.

`SimpleMailMessage` has a copy constructor, so you should do it like this:

```
<bean id="mailService" class="net.bbb.core.service.impl.MailServiceImpl">
    <property name="sender" ref="mailSender"/>
    <property name="template" ref="adminMailTemplate"/>
</bean>
```

and

```
private SimpleMailMessage template;

public void setTemplate(SimpleMailMessage template) {
   this.template = template;
}

public void sendMail() {
    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage(template);
    message.setSubject("Subject");
    message.setText("msg body");          

    try {
        getSender().send(message);
    } catch (MailException e) {
        log.error("Error sending mail!",e);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Trick: There's nothing else in the information you've given us that would cause your issue.

Comment: It must be something with libraries. I will revert everything.

Comment: @Trick: Don't revert everything. Revert one thing at a time until you nail down which specific change broke it. Scientific method, and all that.

Comment: Yes, of course :) It is not important at the moment, so I will leave this, when I'll have time. And I will report, what happens. Thanks!